# Hibernate 4 doesn't create tables when deployed inside Tomcat 7/8

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, hbm2ddl

Yes this sounds crazy, but I'm when I deploy my WAR inside Tomcat, the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" properties are ignored. I have a Spring MVC project that I'm using Maven to build a WAR. When that WAR is deployed I can see from the logs that it just isn't creating/updating the tables as expected.

If I run an integration test (using junit and Spring's mock servlet) than it works fine, or if I deploy the same JAR to Jetty it works as well. Hibernate works/fails similarly for both H2 & MySQL.

When run inside of Tomcat, my database can connect to the database perfectly well if the tables already exist, querying works fine too, it is only that they aren't created/updated.

I thought it was maybe my version of Tomcat 7, so I upgraded to Tomcat 8 but it still didn't work. I've tried it on my machine and up on Elastic Beanstalk.

It isn't a huge problem, but it is a very annoying unsolved mystery, if anyone has any ideas I'd be greatly appreciative!

Stuff gets configured based on the environment, but to give an idea of what it would look like

hibernate config…

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource, Environment environment) throws IOException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("...removed...");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.test.properties");
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.load(resource.getInputStream());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public BoneCPDataSource dataSource(Environment environment) throws Exception {
        BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig("test");

        return new BoneCPDataSource(config);
    }
}
```

hibernate.test.properties…

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

bonecp-config.xml…

```
<named-config name="development">
    <property name="jdbcUrl">jdbc:mysql://localhost/musicdev</property>
    <property name="username">root</property>
    <property name="password"></property>
</named-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting meta-data-complete attribute to false in the root element of your web.xml?

Comment: I tried adding that and it didn't seem to have any effect. Since my application is still starting and running fine (minus not creating/updating the tables), I am pretty sure it is finding my @ WebApplicationInitializer which is what that parameter would affect, right?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time deleting code out of my project piece by piece, config by config until I was left with nothing extra other than my WebAppInitializer and PersistenceJPAConfig classes. So I figured at that point it wasn't likely something I was doing. So I started removing maven dependencies from the pom.xml that weren't being used and eventually figured it out.

For some reason, unbeknownst to me, because a dependency 3 levels down was including log4j:log4j:1.2.14, it stopped everything from working. I verified as best I could, reverted everything back to my last commit, and added an  for that dependency. Lo and behold, Hibernate behaves exactly as you would expect creating/updating tables. If anyone has any idea how that could affect anything without giving a warning of any kind, and how that would be affected by a application container, I'd love to hear it!